# minipages in bidi-longtable

Tags: longtable, minipage, bidi

I have a `bidi-longtable` in a mixed language document (`mainlanguage` Arabic).  I am using minipages in each cell of the table because I will need to do some complicated things later like footnotes.  The dimensions and visible borders and fonts are not important.

What is tricky for me is the right / left alignment within the cell.
And further, the `longtable` affects the section heading.  If I comment out the section with the `longtable`, the section heading is formatted nicely.  But as soon as I put in the `longtable` the section heading is indented weirdly.

I want to achieve this:
[image: Imgur]

But I get this:
[image: Imgur]

My MWE is not behaving.  I have tried putting in `%` at the end of some lines because this seems to be a magic setting in TeX, but even this dark magic is not helping.

To make your answer even more helpful, could you please also explain why my code doesn't work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bidi-longtable}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.50]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}


\section{بببببب \\%
\mbox{}\hfill\textenglish{bbbbbbb}}%

\begin{Arabic}
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة .\end{Arabic}

\begin{english}
word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\end{english}

\begin{longtable}{p{2in}|p{2in}}
\begin{minipage}{2in}
\begin{Arabic}
كلمة 
\end{Arabic}%

\raggedleft 
\begin{english}
word \end{english}
\end{minipage}%
&
\begin{minipage}{2in}
\begin{english}
word 
\end{english}
\end{minipage}%
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `bidi-longtable` is experimental; there is no way in TeX--XeT algorithm to make tabular material RTL except putting it inside

```
\hbox{\beginR\vbox{...}\endR}
```

construction. This has its own set of problems which adds up to TeX--XeT limitation.

A minimal example showing the problem is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\hbox{\beginR\vbox{%
\section{%
This is a test\\
\mbox{}\hfill\LRE{Another test}%
}%
}\endR}

\begin{LTR}
\lipsum[1]
\end{LTR}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the file `latex-xetex-bidi.def`, redefines `\@hangform` as:

```
\def\@hangfrom#1{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1}}%
      \hangindent \if@RTL-\else\fi\wd\@tempboxa\noindent\box\@tempboxa}
```

This redefinition is logical but if it ends up inside the following construction:

```
\hbox{\beginR\vbox{...}\endR}
```

Then margins will be opposite. With your minimal working example, I suggest the following redefinition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bidi-longtable}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.50]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\def\@hangfrom#1{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1}}%
      \hangindent \wd\@tempboxa\noindent\box\@tempboxa}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\section{بببببب \\%
\mbox{}\hfill\textenglish{bbbbbbb}}%

\begin{Arabic}
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة .\end{Arabic}

\begin{english}
word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\end{english}

\begin{longtable}{p{2in}|p{2in}}
\begin{minipage}{2in}
\begin{Arabic}
كلمة 
\end{Arabic}%

\raggedleft 
\begin{english}
word \end{english}
\end{minipage}%
&
\begin{minipage}{2in}
\begin{english}
word 
\end{english}
\end{minipage}%
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Note that this is not a perfect solution; it only fixes your problem but breaks the `bidi` package.

Comment: at least i understand the problem better!